# How to shutdown a single application in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I would like to run some code, in my webapplication, to cause the application to stop. For example, if the database server is unavailable.
I would like to implement something like `App.exit()` similar to `System.exit()`.

**FYI**

The answer in "[Shutdown tomcat using web application deployed in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8799991/2381157)" is about shutting down the whole container. The question here is about shutting down (or temporary disabling) a single web application.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the browser to detect that the server is unavailable and display something appropriate or that you want the web server to detect that the database server is unavailable and generate changed response to the browser?

Comment: @christutty, it doesn't matter to me how it is detected. I would like the server to know that the application must not process any request.

Comment: In that case this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8799991/2381157.  Yes?

Comment: @christutty - It looks like it but I think it's a different question.

Comment: Hmm.  A better match looks like http://stackoverflow.com/q/19365769/2381157, which asks about invoking application manager from a web application.  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application provides a url to issue a shutdown which the application should be able to call in the same way as you'd make a server-side call to any web api.  That seems better than having the code abort because Tomcat should gracefully close the container but it's a different approach to what you're asking for.

Comment: Another similar question with some info is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16377749/2381157.  That's about aborting startup but the answer I've linked suggests that "System.exit() is ugly but it will work ..."

Comment: I would write a background thread that continuously monitors the db status and take the action. System.exit() here might bring down the JVM (Tomcat instance) as a whole and is not recommended. Instead set a flag at application level to indicate the temporary down state. You could use these flag in your servlet filter to notify your users accordingly

Comment: I would expect this to be handled in a filter inside your webapp.  If anything is broken the filter handles the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shutdown a single application in Tomcat, using MBeans/JMX:

```java
public void shutdownApp() {
    try {
        String serviceName = "Catalina"; // @see server.xml
        String hostName = "localhost"; // @see server.xml
        String contextName = "MyApplicationName"; // the name of your application in the URL

        Hashtable<String, String> keys = new Hashtable<>();
        keys.put("j2eeType", "WebModule");
        keys.put("name", "//" + hostName + "/" + contextName);
        keys.put("J2EEApplication", "none");
        keys.put("J2EEServer", "none");

        MBeanServerConnection mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName appObject = ObjectName.getInstance(serviceName, keys);
        System.out.println("Found objectName: " + appObject);
        mbeanServer.invoke(appObject, "stop", null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The serviceName, hostName and contextName vars need to be changed according to your configuration. This example will shutdown an app that is deployed like this:

```
hxxp://localhost:8080/MyApplicationName
```

Beside "stop" you may also call: "start" or "reload".

Answer (score 1):

Usually we dont call App.exit or System.exit in a web application. If Database server is not avilable only the reason or kind of similar issue you can do the following

1. Write a ContextListner implmenting [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)
2. On contextInitialized method check necessary application init configurations like set up DB connections, default configuration etc.,
3. Incase any errors in context initilzation, keep your servlet and jsp pages informed that application is not ready and redirect to error page.

Also using tomcat manager you can start/stop/deploy any webapps in your tomcat container.

Comment: "keep your servlet and jsp pages informed" - is there a centralized way to do it or do I need to add code to every page / servlet?

Comment: need to do it yourself, you will be getting db connection error right?