# How to start/stop/reload a webapplication in Tomcat programatically using Mbeans/JMX

Tags: java, tomcat

I would like to start/stop/reload my web application running in Tomcat programmatically. However, I don't want to restart tomcat, but just the application.

I found the answer in this linked post and the answer by Stefan is what I needed [How to shutdown a single application in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693333/how-to-shutdown-a-single-application-in-tomcat)

However the solution doesn't work for me. It fails with the below exception:

`Found objectName: Catalina:J2EEServer=none,name=//localhost/adapaconsole,J2EEApplication=none,j2eeType=WebModule
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:J2EEServer=none,name=//localhost/adapaconsole,J2EEApplication=none,j2eeType=WebModule
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Test2.shutdownApp(Test2.java:24)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:31)`

My tomcat is running on port 8081 instead of 8080. Any additional changes to be done in the code due to that?

Side note: My application name is adapaconsole

Comment: @Stefan : Could you please help me out?